# SSRS PDF compression

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, compression

When I generate a PDF with MS Reporting Services (server side), the resulting file is 5 times larger in size when compared to the same PDF from another program.

The report contains 1 page with a JPG image of 20kb and text ('Arial' 10px).

PDF rendered in SSRS: 150kb
with the image removed: 120kb
without image or text: 30kb

PDF from other system: 30 kb

Are there any compression settings?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are no pdf export options.

A workaround could be using a PDF virtual printer, and "print" the report instead of using export